# INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE BSOD

Tags: bsod, windows-10-upgrade, toshiba-laptop

I bought a Windows 8 Toshiba laptop. I've had my fair share of problems with it, but I could always refresh and my computer would work fine.

Once I upgraded to Windows 10 though, things changed. I don't think Windows 10 alone is the problem, because I've had some viruses and slowdown before due to irresponsible usage.

This time,it got so bad that my computer started talking about not having enough RAM or something to even close gamemaker, so I always had to force close it. When I decided to refresh, an error occurred.

So I tried again and another error popped up. I try the third time and now I have an INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE error. I let it reload over and over but to no avail.

I've tried to find safe mode, but my computer never gives me the option like in the tutorials.

I tried to make a recovery drive but my other computer only makes recovery discs, this is an issue for me because, my computer won't read discs.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: It sounds like a fresh install of windows is in order. Boot the windows cd given with your laptop and it will give you the option to do a fresh install.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should've made this more clear than I did, but my laptop doesn't read CDs.

Comment: Use a bootable image on a USB drive.

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove the OP has said he can't boot from anything at all.

Comment: @JelaniStowers can you check in the BIOS to see if your harddrive is still listed in there? Can you also check the boot order options to check that your CD drive is set to be the primary boot device? You can access the BIOS by pressing either `F2`, `F8` or `DEL` on boot.

Answer (score 0):

In cases such as these, my usual solution is to pull out the hard drive and connect it to a working computer as a slave, and then run checkdisk on it.  Often, Windows itself will find a problem during the boot process and correct it automatically.  That will also tell you whether the problem is a physical problem on the disk, or software corruption.

Comment: That’s more of a comment. This BSOD has one very specific reason: “This bug check indicates that the Microsoft Windows operating system has lost access to the system partition during startup.” Usually, it’s a missing driver after switching storage devices around.